# Max value in one table does not match value in another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I reviewed many answers about pulling a max value with a corresponding value from another column in the **same** table, but not when the corresponding column lives in **another** table.

Consider:

[image]

I'd like to pull one row for the max bucket_id (62715659), with it's corresponding payor_name value (HSN). The payor_name, however, lives in another table.

Like so:

[image]

Instead, when I run this query:

```
select 
    hsp_account_id
    ,bucket_id
    ,epm.payor_name
from hsp_bucket bkt
left join clarity_epm epm on bkt.payor_id = epm.payor_id 
where bucket_id in (select max(bucket_id) from hsp_bucket)
```

I return 0 rows.

Here is some sample data from both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE hsp_bucket

  (
  hsp_account_id VarChar(50),
bucket_id NUMERIC(18,0),
payor_id NUMERIC(18,0)
 );

 INSERT INTO hsp_bucket
 VALUES
  ('A', 10706486, NULL),
  ('A', 10706487, NULL),
  ('A', 10706488, NULL),
  ('A', 10706491, 1118),
  ('A', 10706489, 3004),
  ('A', 10706490, 4001),
  ('A', 62715659, 4001)


CREATE TABLE clarity_epm
(payor_id NUMERIC(18,0),
payor_name VarChar(50)
 );

 INSERT INTO clarity_epm
 VALUES
  (1118, 'BMCHP ALLI ACO'),
  (3004, 'MEDICAID LIMITED'),
  (4001, 'HSN')
```

Comment: We need sample data from both tables to determine what is happening.

Comment: I added some information above. hsp_bucket table has hsp_account_id, bucket_id and payor_id columns. The clarity_epm table has payor_id and payor_name columns.

Comment: We need sample initial data from *both* tables in order to test your query. And please share your data as formatted text rather than images so it can be copy and pasted out. DDL/DML statements to create the test data is even better.

Comment: Hi Dale, sorry about that. I added some sample data from both tables with the data types that are used. Is this more helpful?

Comment: Great work on the DDL/DML! The only problem is, that produces the result you want? So either your query works, or the sample data isn't representative.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm.... I'll have to think about that. My attempted query isn't pulling what I want. So I'm not sure.